# karger min cut algorithm using networkX is very slow in running time

Tags: python, performance, networkx

new to python. Try to use the networkX package to get work done but it seems to have much longer running time than "creating a list of list" to represent graph. Is that just because the data structure of nextworkX  too much for this simple task?
BTW, the result will output twice of the answer. Because the read_adjlist function will count same edge twice for u and v nodes in the file. Is there any way to avoid this and also allow the recognition of parallel edge?

Thanks all.

```
import networkx as nx
import random

Graph_Adjacency_List = "***.txt"
handle = open(Graph_Adjacency_List, 'r')
G=nx.read_adjlist(handle,create_using=nx.MultiGraph(), nodetype=int)

def cut(G):
    while G.number_of_nodes()>2 :
        u,v= random.choice(G.edges())
        G = nx.contracted_edge(G, (u, v), self_loops=False)
    return G.number_of_edges()

m=100
for i in range(1000):
    random.seed()
    c=cut(G)
    if c< m:
        m=c
        print m
```

Comment: Just a quick comment on why this is slow:  `nx.contracted_edge` returns a brand new graph with the edge contracted.  It leaves the original graph alone.  So each time through the `while` in `cut`, it generates a new graph.  That's probably what's slowing things down.  You could avoid this by creating your own function to contract edges that modifies the graph.  If you do this, you should send a copy of G rather than G into cut.

Comment: yeah, the contracted function keeps the original one intact. But G is local variable in function cut and gets updated at every contraction. The G in the for loop is the same all the time but copies sent to cut at each iteration.  @joel

Comment: My point is that this is very slow.  Each time you call `nx.contracted_edge` it creates a new graph. That means, all of the nodes and all of the edges are recreated.  This is almost certainly the vast majority of the runtime.  If you simply create a single copy before `cut` and then modify that copy, it won't have to recreate a new graph each time.

Comment: Got your point. Guess I have to write the modification version of contracted_edge to make it quick. @Joel

Answer (score 2):

To solve the double counting on the edges I simply returned:

```
int(G.number_of_edges()/2)
```

Instead of:

```
G.number_of_edges()
```

To solve the problem with the algorithm being slow I didn´t use nx.contracted_edge, that function returns a new graph, taking a lot of time like others commented. I did the operation in place, looking at the source code for nx.contracted_edge and swapping H with G:

```
new_edges = ((u, w, d) for x, w, d in G.edges(v, data=True)
                 if False or w != u)
v_data = G.node[v]
G.remove_node(v)
G.add_edges_from(new_edges)
if 'contraction' in G.node[u]:
    G.node[u]['contraction'][v] = v_data
else:
    G.node[u]['contraction'] = {v: v_data}
```